# How to delete an object from array?

Tags: javascript, react-native

so i have a store that looks like this:

```
export class NoteStore {
    notes = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Shopping list',
            children: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Sweet',
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            name: 'Chocolate',
                        },
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            name: 'Fudge'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 5,
                            name: 'Cookies'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

i am trying to remove an item from items by pressing a button. so far i have managed to make a remove function that does not throw an error but it doesn't do anything. i have spent so much time with this but i just can't figure out what i need to do to get the removing working properly. this is what i'm working with:

```
const store = useContext(NoteStore);

function removeItems(id) {
        store.notes = store.notes.filter(item => item !== id);
    }

//Prints notes content to the screen
    const NotesArray = () => {
        return store.notes[0].children[0].items.map((item) =>
            <View key={item.id} style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <Text style={styles.note}>{item.name}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{ justifyContent:'center', paddingLeft:5 }} onPress={() => {
                    removeItems(item.id);
                }}>
                    <Text>
                        <Icon name={noteDeleteMode ? 'close-circle-outline': null} style={styles.deleteIcon} />
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently comparing the `id` with the whole `item`, not with it's `id`.

Replace

```
store.notes = store.notes.filter(item => item !== id);
```

with

```
store.notes = store.notes.filter(item => item.id !== id);
```

(`item.id` instead of just `item`)

Comment: now it's get filtered, but the elements not rerendered, because you not `setState`

Comment: on a `noteStore` context use `useState` for `notes` and `setNotes` and send both (the object and the update function) in the `contextProvider`. then use the `stNotes` to update the notes such as it will set state nd update the related components

Comment: check here: https://dev.to/efearas/how-to-usecontext-and-set-value-of-context-in-child-components-in-3-steps-3j9h

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand how i can implement the contextProvider for  my code. i tried this `const [items, setItems] = useState(store);`  and added this line `setItems(store.notes);` to the function but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is that you're saving the reference to the old `store.notes` somewhere. Fortunately, you don't need to create a new array; you can just modify the old one. Use this:

```js
function removeItems(id) {
    store.notes.splice(store.notes.findIndex(item => item.id === id), 1);
}
```

Comment: when i use this i get an error: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'notes[0].name')`

Comment: That's not an error caused by this code. I tested it and there's nothing in this code referencing `notes[0].name`.

Comment: oops yeah i found the source of the error. but the function still doesn't seem to work..

Comment: do you have any more advice?

Comment: @orvokki I tested it and it works. Try to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.